# How to connect MS SQL Database with Azure Databricks and run command

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, pyspark, databricks

I want to connect Azure MS SQL Database with Azure Databricks via python spark. I could do this with pushdown_query if I run Select * from.... But I need to run `ALTER DATABASE` to scale up/down.

I must change this part

```
spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
```

otherwise I get this error *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.*

Anyone can help me. Much appreciated.

```
jdbcHostname = "xxx.database.windows.net"
jdbcDatabase = "abc"
jdbcPort = 1433


jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" :  "..............",
  "password" : "............",
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

pushdown_query = "(ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S0')) dual_down" 
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

Comment: Why the brackets `(ALTER` and an extra one again at the end. And what's `dual_down`

Comment: i assume it is jbdc's syntax, i referred from :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases#python-example  dual_down is only alias, i want to there to decrease service objective to S0 in azure ms server.

Comment: Don't know Spark or Python so could be wrong, but it looks like `spark.read` means the driver is effectively sending `SELECT * FROM (ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S0')) dual_down` I think you might want `spark.sql` instead